# What symmetry corresponds to the square of a complex number, as opposed to the norm?

Tags: lie-groups, symmetric-groups

If I claim that the norm of a complex vector is to remain constant $|z|^2=(a+ib)(a-ib)=a^2+b^2$, then I obtain the U(1) symmetry (I think?).

My questions is; if I claim that the square of a complex vector is to remain constant $z^2= (a+ib)^2=a^2-b^2+2iab$, what is the resulting symmetry? In the latter case both the real and the imaginary part must be held constant: (1): $a^2-b^2$ and (2) $ab$.

So

- is it the case that the constraint $a^2+b^2=C$ is invariant with
  respect to U(1)?
- What symmetric group is produced by the constraints of $a^2-b^2=C$ and $ab=D$.

Comment: Reflection symmetry $(x,y) \rightarrow (-x,-y)$ preserves the square.

Comment: $z^2 = a^2-b^2+2iab$

Comment: Think about it visually.  Both constraints define hyperbolas.  Where do those hyperbolas intersect?

Comment: @Paul so, a pair of intersecting lines? [see figure](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Ba*b%3D%3Da%5E2-b%5E2%7D)

Comment: The question is a bit vague but interesting. The maps which preserve $x^2-y^2$ are the Lorentz transformations of the plane. But you need to preserve $xy$ as well. I think that Paul is right, and ultimately the only transformation that preserves everything is $z\mapsto -z$.

Comment: A little simultaneous equations and quadratic equation magic does indeed prove that it is just the identity map or the inversion map listed above ($(x,y)\mapsto(-x,-y)$). The group is just $\Bbb Z_2$.

Answer (score 3):

If the norm of a complex number remains constant, then $z$ lies on a circle, as you've stated:  $|z|^2=a^2+b^2 = \textrm{const.}$

For $z^2$ to remain constant, it is the intersection of two hyperbolas, and is two points:

$z=z_0$ and $z=-z_0$.

(Every non-zero complex number has two square roots.)

**Update (a few more details):**

If $z^2= r_0 e^{i\theta_0}$, 
then $z \in \{ r_0^{1/2} e^{{i\theta_0}/{2}} , r_0^{1/2} e^{i(\theta_0/2+\pi)}\}$